# How to append two values to a single parameter in html form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This form creates and redirect people to a link depending on their selection!
They need to select engine make, power range and then their location.

The current values in engine make and power range are for Australia location, but if they select America I'm gonna need different values!

Question: is It possible to have two different values for each item and the location will determine which value to use when creating the link!

```
<input type="radio" id="enginemake1" name="enginemake" value="6" checked/><label for="enginemake1">Chevrolet</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="enginemake2" name="enginemake" value="8"/><label for="enginemake2">Chrysler</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="enginemake3" name="enginemake" value="7"/><label for="enginemake3">Ford</label><br>


<select id="powerrange" name="powerrange">
<option id="powerrange1" value="128">200 HP</option>
<option id="powerrange2" value="178">250 HP</option>
<option id="powerrange3" value="228" selected>300 HP</option>
<option id="powerrange4" value="278">350 HP</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" id="location1" name="location" value="store" checked/><label for="location1">America</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="location2" name="location" value="store.au"/><label for="location2">Australia</label><br>


<script type="text/javascript">


function goToPage(){
    var location = $('input[name=location]:checked').val();
    var department = $('input[name=department]:checked').val();
    var enginemake = $('input[name=enginemake]:checked').val();
    var powerrange = document.getElementById("powerrange").value;

    window.location.href = "http://"+location+".domain.com/catalog.aspx?section=-"+enginemake+"-"+powerrange+"-";
}
</script>
```

Comment: If all of the locations have the same number of power ranges, and the same number of engine makes, this would lend itself to an associative array (or javascript object). `cars = {'store': {'1' : '225 HP', '2': '250 HP'}, 'store.au' : {'1' : '200 HP', '2' : '220 HP'}}` and accessed by `cars[location][powerrange]`. You could also do this using an array/object and have the select options change when the user changes the location selector (so they could see the actual power range options for that location)

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k3qFz/) is a fiddle to show the latter.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler The labels are the same! people will choose 250 HP or 200 HP, but when the link is created the value for each will be different depending on the location!

Comment: @MichaelWheeler Let's say if they select 200 HP and Australia the value will be 128 but if they select 200 HP Amaerica the value will be 258... different values but same labels!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the value of each option as JSON:

```
<select id="powerrange" name="powerrange">
    <option id="powerrange1" value='{"store":128,"store.au":258}'>200 HP</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then modify the goToPage() method as follows:

```
function goToPage(){
    var location = $('input[name=location]:checked').val();
    var department = $('input[name=department]:checked').val();
    var enginemake = $('input[name=enginemake]:checked').val();
    var powerrange = document.getElementById("powerrange").value;
    var json = $.parseJSON(powerrange);
    console.log(json[location]);

    console.log("http://"+location+".domain.com/catalog.aspx?section=-"+enginemake+"-"+json[location]+"-");
}
```

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EeKx/) for a demo